# Django: Ordering Objects Manually w/ A Field

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a django model with an `index` IntegerField.

I want to allow users to manually order these objects via a drag and drop interface.

The idea is to update the ordering by updating this `index` field when one of the objects is dragged to a new position. So, for example if a user drags the 4th item to the top, that object will then be index 0, former index 0 will be index 1, former index 1 will be shifted to index 2 and so on.

Is there a good way to do this in a single Django ORM call, without needing to iterate through the entire list of objects and increment the index? Say I want to insert an object that was at Index 4 at Index 2– is there a way to shift all indexes >= 2 by +1?

Comment: I suggest keeping the index order for *each* user would be an option, with the help of a separate, related tables.

Comment: You can use a `FloatField` instead of an `IntegerField` and set the new value to the arithmetic average of the previous and next index.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu the question is more about how to deal with inserting and reordering. even if i used a separate table and per-user ordering i would still need to iterate and reorder, no?

Comment: @Selcuk Interesting– but this would surely have some weird results right? This this a common way of doing it? Seems weird that my API response might have order: 0, order 0.5, and order 1.0

Comment: If the `index` field is visible, yes, it would be weird. I was assuming that it would be an internal field to be used for ordering only.

Comment: with the drag and drop feature your interface will somehow involve javascript I assume. It will be easier doing it in the js side. On a mouseup event ( when user dropping the item to a new position), reassign the indexes, then save to the django backend via normal post method or ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1

A way to do this with a single query/ORM call, without looping too, is:

```
from django.db.models import F, Case, IntegerField, When, Value

# 'i' is the original index of the item that was moved
IndexedModel.objects.filter(user=user, index__gte=i).update(
     index=Case(When(index=i, then=Value(0)), 
                default=F('index')+1,
                output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)
```

This produces the following SQL (or similar) (assuming `i=4` and `user='zee'`):

```
UPDATE "index" SET "index" = CASE WHEN ("indexed_model"."index" = 4) THEN 0 ELSE ("indexed_model"."index" + 1) END WHERE "indexed_model"."index" >= 4 AND "indexed_model"."user" = "zee"'
```

Note that of course you would need a linking model (e.g. `IndexedModel` above) that associates each user with an order of the items, like

```
class IndexedModel(django.models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, models.CASCADE)
    index = models.IntegerField()
```

### Method 2

You can definitely further develop @Selcuk's idea of using `FloatField()` as `index` and then taking the average of the *preceding item* and *succeeding item* surrounding the target position. But like you mentioned, you'd lose the integers and the ability to meaningfully display the order explicitly.

Note that in that approach you should **not** make your first index `0`, but `1` instead; if not you wouldn't be able to insert into the `0` position, since **the average of positive numbers** would never yield `0`, except they are all `0`, and `0` is the minimum **non-negative** index you'd get.

For instance, with indexes 0,1,2,3, inserting into first position would mean simply assigning 0 directly, with a clash, but with 1,2,3,4, you can do `(0+1)/2=0.5`, where `0` is for the `null` that would be returned in the position for *preceding item*.

Comment: Nice ideas! I think in method 1 it should be actually `lte` instead of `gte`

Comment: @TCFDS indeed, you're right. Mostly. I think the algorithm in Method 1 actually needs refining -- it's not totally correct. It should rather deal with the region between the old position and the new position, and cater to both dragging upwards (lower index) and dragging downwards (to higher index).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't necessarily need to do it yourself, I'd use an existing package for that, like https://github.com/jrief/django-admin-sortable2.